Как сделать функцию в Python на QT
Есть приложение, подскажите как сделать так, чтобы можно было вносить свои параметры "Пропорции" inputPropCitySummer, "Нормы расхода" inputNormCitySummer 
и при нажатии на кнопку "Применить" applyPropCitySummer и applyNormCitySummer программа сохраняла внесенное в переменные propCity и normCity?

app.py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
from design import Ui_root

sys.argv += ['-platform', 'windows:darkmode=1']


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_root):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)
    
            self.btnSummer.clicked.connect(self.funcSummer)
            self.outSummer.show()
            self.btnWinter.clicked.connect(self.funcWinter)
            self.outWinter.show()
    
            self.btnAbout.clicked.connect(self.funcAbout)
            self.btnHelp.clicked.connect(self.funcHelp)
    
            self.btnGear.setCheckable(True)
            self.btnGear.clicked.connect(self.funcGear)
    
        def funcGear(self):
            if self.btnGear.isChecked():
                self.resize(560, 670)
            else:
                self.resize(560, 450)
    
        def funcSummer(self):
            try:
                propCity = 0.3 or float(self.inputPropCitySummer.text())
                propHighway = 0.7 or float(self.inputPropHighwaySummer.text())
                normCity = 11.5 or float(self.inputNormCitySummer.text())
                normHighway = 8.5 or float(self.inputNormHighwaySummer.text())
    
                inSummer = float(self.inputSummer.text())
                roadCity = round(propCity * inSummer, 2)
                roadHighway = round(propHighway * inSummer, 2)
                resultCity = round(propCity * inSummer / 100 * normCity, 2)
                resultHighway = round(propHighway * inSummer / 100 * normHighway, 2)
                totalSummer = round((propCity * inSummer / 100 * normCity) + (propHighway * inSummer / 100 * normHighway), 2)
                totalCity = round(inSummer / 100 * normCity, 2)
                totalHighway = round(inSummer / 100 * normHighway, 2)
    
                self.outSummer.setText(
                    f' '
                    f'Ваш пробег по городу {roadCity} км\n Потрачено по городу {resultCity} литров\n'
                    f' Ваш пробег по трассе {roadHighway} км\n Потрачено по трассе {resultHighway} литров\n\n'
                    f' Ваш общий расход {totalSummer} литров\n\n'
                    f' Нормы расхода\n'
                    f' Город {normCity} на 100 км\n'
                    f' Трасса {normHighway} на 100 км\n\n'
                    f' Город 100% {totalCity} литров\n'
                    f' Трасса 100% {totalHighway} литров'
                )
            except Exception as e:
                msg = QMessageBox.information(
                    self, 'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так. \n"
                                      f"Проверьте исходные данные.")
    
        def funcWinter(self):
    
            try:
                inWinter = float(self.inputWinter.text())
                roadCity = round(0.3 * float(inWinter), 2)
                roadHighway = round(0.7 * float(inWinter), 2)
                resultCity = round(0.3 * float(inWinter) / 100 * 13.8, 2)
                resultHighway = round(0.7 * float(inWinter) / 100 * 10.2, 2)
                totalWinter = round((0.3 * inWinter / 100 * 13.8) + (0.7 * inWinter / 100 * 10.2), 2)
                """totalCity = round(float(inWinter) / 100 * 13.8, 2)
                totalHighway = round(float(inWinter) / 100 * 10.2, 2)"""
    
                self.outWinter.setText(
                    f''
                    f' Ваш пробег по городу {roadCity} км\n Потрачено по городу {resultCity} литров\n\n'
                    f' Ваш пробег по трассе {roadHighway} км\n Потрачено по трассе {resultHighway} литров\n\n'
                    f' Ваш общий расход {totalWinter} литров\n\n'
                    f' Нормы расхода\n'
                    f' Город: 13.8 на 100 км\n'
                    f' Трасса: 10.2 на 100 км\n'
                )
    
            except Exception as e:
                msg = QMessageBox.information(
                    self, 'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так. \n"
                                      f"Проверьте исходные данные.")
    
        def funcAbout(self):
            strAbout = """
                BenzConfig ver. 0.7\n
                Copyright © Чекаев В.А.
                Ресурсы www.flaticon.com\n
                Лицензия
                GNU General Public License v3.0
                """
    
            msgAbout = QMessageBox()
            msgAbout.setWindowTitle("About")
            msgAbout.setWindowIcon(QIcon('infoMenu.svg'))
    
            msgAbout.setText(strAbout)
            msgAbout.setIconPixmap(QPixmap("iconAbout.png"))
    
            msgAbout.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            msgAbout.exec()
    
        def funcHelp(self):
            strAbout = """
            Пропорции перерасчета расхода
            город/трасса 30% на 70%\n
            HOTKEYS
            Рассчет Летнего пробега клавиша "Enter"
            Рассчет Зимнего пробега клавиша "Tab"
                """
    
            msgAbout = QMessageBox()
            msgAbout.setWindowTitle("Help")
            msgAbout.setWindowIcon(QIcon('helpMenu.svg'))
    
            msgAbout.setText(strAbout)
            msgAbout.setIconPixmap(QPixmap("IconHelp.png"))
    
            msgAbout.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            msgAbout.exec()
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        app.setStyle('Fusion')
        w = MainWindow()
        w.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())

design.py
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMainWindow,
    QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QTabWidget, QWidget)
import files_rc

class Ui_root(object):
    def setupUi(self, root):
        if not root.objectName():
            root.setObjectName(u"root")
        root.resize(560, 450)
        root.setMinimumSize(QSize(560, 450))
        root.setMaximumSize(QSize(560, 670))
        root.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
        root.setMouseTracking(False)
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(u":/icon/icon.ico", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        root.setWindowIcon(icon)
        root.setWindowOpacity(1.000000000000000)
        root.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        root.setStyleSheet(u"")
        root.setDocumentMode(False)
        root.setTabShape(QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.grid_w = QWidget(root)
        self.grid_w.setObjectName(u"grid_w")
        self.grid_w.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.inputSummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputSummer.setObjectName(u"inputSummer")
        self.inputSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 40, 241, 31))
        self.inputSummer.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.inputSummer.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.inputSummer.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.inputSummer.setMaxLength(32767)
        self.inputSummer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.inputSummer.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.outSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.outSummer.setObjectName(u"outSummer")
        self.outSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 130, 241, 281))
        self.outSummer.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 230);")
        self.outSummer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop)
        self.btnSummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnSummer.setObjectName(u"btnSummer")
        self.btnSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 80, 241, 41))
        self.btnSummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnSummer.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.btnSummer.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.btnWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnWinter.setObjectName(u"btnWinter")
        self.btnWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 80, 241, 41))
        self.btnWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnWinter.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.outWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.outWinter.setObjectName(u"outWinter")
        self.outWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 130, 241, 281))
        self.outWinter.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);")
        self.outWinter.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.outWinter.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop)
        self.inputWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputWinter.setObjectName(u"inputWinter")
        self.inputWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 40, 241, 31))
        self.inputWinter.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.inputWinter.setMaxLength(10)
        self.label_s = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.label_s.setObjectName(u"label_s")
        self.label_s.setGeometry(QRect(20, 10, 241, 21))
        self.label_s.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.lable_w = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.lable_w.setObjectName(u"lable_w")
        self.lable_w.setGeometry(QRect(300, 10, 241, 21))
        self.lable_w.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.btnAbout = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnAbout.setObjectName(u"btnAbout")
        self.btnAbout.setGeometry(QRect(20, 417, 29, 28))
        self.btnAbout.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnAbout.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon1 = QIcon()
        icon1.addFile(u"info.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btnAbout.setIcon(icon1)
        self.btnHelp = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnHelp.setObjectName(u"btnHelp")
        self.btnHelp.setGeometry(QRect(50, 417, 30, 28))
        self.btnHelp.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnHelp.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon2 = QIcon()
        icon2.addFile(u"help.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btnHelp.setIcon(icon2)
        self.btnHelp.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.btnHelp.setFlat(False)
        self.btnGear = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnGear.setObjectName(u"btnGear")
        self.btnGear.setGeometry(QRect(510, 417, 30, 28))
        self.btnGear.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnGear.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon3 = QIcon()
        icon3.addFile(u"gear.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btnGear.setIcon(icon3)
        self.labelPropSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelPropSummer.setObjectName(u"labelPropSummer")
        self.labelPropSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 470, 71, 16))
        self.applyPropCitySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setObjectName(u"applyPropCitySummer")
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 490, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.labelNormSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelNormSummer.setObjectName(u"labelNormSummer")
        self.labelNormSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 570, 91, 16))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"applyNormHighwaySummer")
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 630, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"applyPropHighwaySummer")
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 530, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyNormCitySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setObjectName(u"applyNormCitySummer")
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 590, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.defis = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.defis.setObjectName(u"defis")
        self.defis.setGeometry(QRect(20, 440, 521, 20))
        self.defis.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 200);")
        self.applyNormCityWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setObjectName(u"applyNormCityWinter")
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 590, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"applyNormHighwayWinter")
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 630, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyPropCityWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setObjectName(u"applyPropCityWinter")
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 490, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"applyPropHighwayWinter")
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 530, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.labelPropWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelPropWinter.setObjectName(u"labelPropWinter")
        self.labelPropWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 470, 71, 16))
        self.labelNormWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelNormWinter.setObjectName(u"labelNormWinter")
        self.labelNormWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 570, 91, 16))
        self.inputPropCitySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setObjectName(u"inputPropCitySummer")
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 491, 151, 31))
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"inputPropHighwaySummer")
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 530, 151, 31))
        self.inputPropCityWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setObjectName(u"inputPropCityWinter")
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 490, 151, 31))
        self.inputPropHighwayWInter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropHighwayWInter.setObjectName(u"inputPropHighwayWInter")
        self.inputPropHighwayWInter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 530, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormCitySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setObjectName(u"inputNormCitySummer")
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 590, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"inputNormHighwaySummer")
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 630, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormCityWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setObjectName(u"inputNormCityWinter")
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 590, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormHighwayWInter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormHighwayWInter.setObjectName(u"inputNormHighwayWInter")
        self.inputNormHighwayWInter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 630, 151, 31))
        root.setCentralWidget(self.grid_w)

        self.retranslateUi(root)

        self.btnHelp.setDefault(False)
        self.btnGear.setDefault(False)


        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(root)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, root):
        root.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"BenzConfig", None))
        self.inputSummer.setInputMask("")
        self.inputSummer.setText("")
        self.inputSummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435", None))
        self.outSummer.setText("")
        self.btnSummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnSummer.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"Return", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnWinter.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"Space", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.outWinter.setText("")
        self.inputWinter.setText("")
        self.inputWinter.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435", None))
        self.label_s.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041b\u0435\u0442\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))
        self.lable_w.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0417\u0438\u043c\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))
        self.btnAbout.setText("")
        self.btnHelp.setText("")
        self.btnGear.setText("")
        self.labelPropSummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0446\u0438\u0438", None))
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.labelNormSummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041d\u043e\u0440\u043c\u044b \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0430", None))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.defis.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"__________________________________________________________________________________________________________", None))
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.labelPropWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0446\u0438\u0438", None))
        self.labelNormWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041d\u043e\u0440\u043c\u044b \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0430", None))
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputPropHighwayWInter.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputNormHighwayWInter.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
    # retranslateUi


Не уверен что правильно понял вас, но как вариант попробуйте так:
import sys
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from design import Ui_root
class Ui_root(object):
    def setupUi(self, root):
        if not root.objectName():
            root.setObjectName(u"root")
        root.resize(560, 450)
        root.setMinimumSize(QSize(560, 450))
        root.setMaximumSize(QSize(560, 670))
        root.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
        root.setMouseTracking(False)
        icon = QIcon()
#        icon.addFile(u":/icon/icon.ico", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
# -------------------> vvvvvv <----------------------------------- установите свое
        icon.addFile(u"Ok.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)        
        root.setWindowIcon(icon)
        root.setWindowOpacity(1.000000000000000)
        root.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        root.setStyleSheet(u"")
        root.setDocumentMode(False)
        root.setTabShape(QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.grid_w = QWidget(root)
        self.grid_w.setObjectName(u"grid_w")
        self.grid_w.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.inputSummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputSummer.setObjectName(u"inputSummer")
        self.inputSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 40, 241, 31))
        self.inputSummer.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.inputSummer.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.inputSummer.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.inputSummer.setMaxLength(32767)
        self.inputSummer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.inputSummer.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.outSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.outSummer.setObjectName(u"outSummer")
        self.outSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 130, 241, 281))
        self.outSummer.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 230);")
        self.outSummer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop)
        self.btnSummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnSummer.setObjectName(u"btnSummer")
        self.btnSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 80, 241, 41))
        self.btnSummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnSummer.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.btnSummer.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.btnWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnWinter.setObjectName(u"btnWinter")
        self.btnWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 80, 241, 41))
        self.btnWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnWinter.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.outWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.outWinter.setObjectName(u"outWinter")
        self.outWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 130, 241, 281))
        self.outWinter.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);")
        self.outWinter.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.outWinter.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop)
        self.inputWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputWinter.setObjectName(u"inputWinter")
        self.inputWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 40, 241, 31))
        self.inputWinter.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.inputWinter.setMaxLength(10)
        self.label_s = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.label_s.setObjectName(u"label_s")
        self.label_s.setGeometry(QRect(20, 10, 241, 21))
        self.label_s.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.lable_w = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.lable_w.setObjectName(u"lable_w")
        self.lable_w.setGeometry(QRect(300, 10, 241, 21))
        self.lable_w.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.btnAbout = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnAbout.setObjectName(u"btnAbout")
        self.btnAbout.setGeometry(QRect(20, 417, 29, 28))
        self.btnAbout.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnAbout.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon1 = QIcon()
#        icon1.addFile(u"info.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
# ------------------->  vvvvvvvv <----------------------------------- установите свое 
        icon1.addFile(u"ball.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btnAbout.setIcon(icon1)
        self.btnHelp = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnHelp.setObjectName(u"btnHelp")
        self.btnHelp.setGeometry(QRect(50, 417, 30, 28))
        self.btnHelp.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnHelp.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon2 = QIcon()
#        icon2.addFile(u"help.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
# ------------------->  vvvvvvvv <----------------------------------- установите свое 
        icon2.addFile(u"ball.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        
        self.btnHelp.setIcon(icon2)
        self.btnHelp.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.btnHelp.setFlat(False)
        self.btnGear = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnGear.setObjectName(u"btnGear")
        self.btnGear.setGeometry(QRect(510, 417, 30, 28))
        self.btnGear.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnGear.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon3 = QIcon()
#        icon3.addFile(u"gear.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
# ------------------->  vvvvvvvv <----------------------------------- установите свое        
        icon3.addFile(u"im.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        
        self.btnGear.setIcon(icon3)
        self.labelPropSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelPropSummer.setObjectName(u"labelPropSummer")
        self.labelPropSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 470, 71, 16))
        self.applyPropCitySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setObjectName(u"applyPropCitySummer")
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 490, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.labelNormSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelNormSummer.setObjectName(u"labelNormSummer")
        self.labelNormSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 570, 91, 16))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"applyNormHighwaySummer")
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 630, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"applyPropHighwaySummer")
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 530, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyNormCitySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setObjectName(u"applyNormCitySummer")
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 590, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.defis = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.defis.setObjectName(u"defis")
        self.defis.setGeometry(QRect(20, 440, 521, 20))
        self.defis.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 200);")
        self.applyNormCityWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setObjectName(u"applyNormCityWinter")
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 590, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"applyNormHighwayWinter")
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 630, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyPropCityWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setObjectName(u"applyPropCityWinter")
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 490, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"applyPropHighwayWinter")
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 530, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.labelPropWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelPropWinter.setObjectName(u"labelPropWinter")
        self.labelPropWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 470, 71, 16))
        self.labelNormWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelNormWinter.setObjectName(u"labelNormWinter")
        self.labelNormWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 570, 91, 16))
        self.inputPropCitySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setObjectName(u"inputPropCitySummer")
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 491, 151, 31))
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"inputPropHighwaySummer")
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 530, 151, 31))
        self.inputPropCityWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setObjectName(u"inputPropCityWinter")
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 490, 151, 31))
        self.inputPropHighwayWInter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropHighwayWInter.setObjectName(u"inputPropHighwayWInter")
        self.inputPropHighwayWInter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 530, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormCitySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setObjectName(u"inputNormCitySummer")
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 590, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"inputNormHighwaySummer")
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 630, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormCityWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setObjectName(u"inputNormCityWinter")
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 590, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormHighwayWInter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormHighwayWInter.setObjectName(u"inputNormHighwayWInter")
        self.inputNormHighwayWInter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 630, 151, 31))
        root.setCentralWidget(self.grid_w)

        self.retranslateUi(root)
        self.btnHelp.setDefault(False)
        self.btnGear.setDefault(False)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(root)

    def retranslateUi(self, root):
        root.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"BenzConfig", None))
        self.inputSummer.setInputMask("")
        self.inputSummer.setText("")
        self.inputSummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435", None))
        self.outSummer.setText("")
        self.btnSummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnSummer.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"Return", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnWinter.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"Space", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.outWinter.setText("")
        self.inputWinter.setText("")
        self.inputWinter.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435", None))
        self.label_s.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041b\u0435\u0442\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))
        self.lable_w.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0417\u0438\u043c\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))
        self.btnAbout.setText("")
        self.btnHelp.setText("")
        self.btnGear.setText("")
        self.labelPropSummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0446\u0438\u0438", None))
# PropCitySummer
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", 
            u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))

        self.labelNormSummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041d\u043e\u0440\u043c\u044b \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0430", None))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
# NormCitySummer
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", 
            u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))

        self.defis.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"__________________________________________________________________________________________________________", None))
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.labelPropWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0446\u0438\u0438", None))
        self.labelNormWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041d\u043e\u0440\u043c\u044b \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0430", None))

#        self.inputPropCitySummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"Город inputPropCitySummer", None))

        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputPropHighwayWInter.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))

#        self.inputNormCitySummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", 
            u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434 inputNormCitySummer", None))

        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputNormHighwayWInter.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))

#? sys.argv += ['-platform', 'windows:darkmode=1']


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_root):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
        self.propCity = None                                         # !!! +++
        self.normCity = None                                         # !!! +++
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.btnSummer.clicked.connect(self.funcSummer)
#?        self.outSummer.show()
        self.btnWinter.clicked.connect(self.funcWinter)
#?        self.outWinter.show()
    
        self.btnAbout.clicked.connect(self.funcAbout)
        self.btnHelp.clicked.connect(self.funcHelp)
    
        self.btnGear.setCheckable(True)
        self.btnGear.clicked.connect(self.funcGear)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.applyPropCitySummer.clicked.connect(self.new_propCity)
        self.applyNormCitySummer.clicked.connect(self.new_normCity)
        
    def new_propCity(self):
        try:
            self.propCity = float(self.inputPropCitySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()
        except Exception as e:
            self.propCity = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputPropCitySummer.text()}</b>")            
        
    def new_normCity(self):
        try:
            self.normCity = float(self.inputNormCitySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normCity = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputNormCitySummer.text()}</b>")          
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        
    
    def funcGear(self):
        if self.btnGear.isChecked():
            self.resize(560, 670)
        else:
            self.resize(560, 450)
    
    def funcSummer(self):
        try:
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
#            propCity = 0.3 or float(self.inputPropCitySummer.text())
#            normCity = 11.5 or float(self.inputNormCitySummer.text())
            if self.propCity: 
                propCity = self.propCity
            else:
                propCity = 0.3
            if self.normCity: 
                normCity = self.normCity
            else:
                normCity = 11.5
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                

            propHighway = 0.7 or float(self.inputPropHighwaySummer.text())
            normHighway = 8.5 or float(self.inputNormHighwaySummer.text())
    
            inSummer = float(self.inputSummer.text())
            roadCity = round(propCity * inSummer, 2)
            roadHighway = round(propHighway * inSummer, 2)
            resultCity = round(propCity * inSummer / 100 * normCity, 2)
            resultHighway = round(propHighway * inSummer / 100 * normHighway, 2)
            totalSummer = round((propCity * inSummer / 100 * normCity) + (propHighway * inSummer / 100 * normHighway), 2)
            totalCity = round(inSummer / 100 * normCity, 2)
            totalHighway = round(inSummer / 100 * normHighway, 2)
    
            self.outSummer.setText(
                f' '
                f'Ваш пробег по городу {roadCity} км\n Потрачено по городу {resultCity} литров\n'
                f' Ваш пробег по трассе {roadHighway} км\n Потрачено по трассе {resultHighway} литров\n\n'
                f' Ваш общий расход {totalSummer} литров\n\n'
                f' Нормы расхода\n'
                f' Город {normCity} на 100 км\n'
                f' Трасса {normHighway} на 100 км\n\n'
                f' Город 100% {totalCity} литров\n'
                f' Трасса 100% {totalHighway} литров'
            )
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так. \n"
                                  f"Проверьте исходные данные.")
    
    def funcWinter(self):
        try:
            inWinter = float(self.inputWinter.text())
            roadCity = round(0.3 * float(inWinter), 2)
            roadHighway = round(0.7 * float(inWinter), 2)
            resultCity = round(0.3 * float(inWinter) / 100 * 13.8, 2)
            resultHighway = round(0.7 * float(inWinter) / 100 * 10.2, 2)
            totalWinter = round((0.3 * inWinter / 100 * 13.8) + (0.7 * inWinter / 100 * 10.2), 2)
            """totalCity = round(float(inWinter) / 100 * 13.8, 2)
            totalHighway = round(float(inWinter) / 100 * 10.2, 2)"""
    
            self.outWinter.setText(
                f''
                f' Ваш пробег по городу {roadCity} км\n Потрачено по городу {resultCity} литров\n\n'
                f' Ваш пробег по трассе {roadHighway} км\n Потрачено по трассе {resultHighway} литров\n\n'
                f' Ваш общий расход {totalWinter} литров\n\n'
                f' Нормы расхода\n'
                f' Город: 13.8 на 100 км\n'
                f' Трасса: 10.2 на 100 км\n'
            )
    
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так. \n"
                                  f"Проверьте исходные данные.")
    
    def funcAbout(self):
        strAbout = """
            BenzConfig ver. 0.7\n
            Copyright © Чекаев В.А.
            Ресурсы www.flaticon.com\n
            Лицензия
            GNU General Public License v3.0
        """
    
        msgAbout = QMessageBox()
        msgAbout.setWindowTitle("About")
#        msgAbout.setWindowIcon(QIcon('infoMenu.svg'))
# --------------------------------->  vvvvvvvvv <------------------ установите свое 
        msgAbout.setWindowIcon(QIcon('image.svg'))
        msgAbout.setText(strAbout)
#        msgAbout.setIconPixmap(QPixmap("iconAbout.png"))
# ---------------------------------->  vvvvvvvvvv <---------------- установите свое 
        msgAbout.setIconPixmap(QPixmap("lena3.png"))
        
        msgAbout.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        msgAbout.exec()
    
    def funcHelp(self):
        strAbout = """
        Пропорции перерасчета расхода
        город/трасса 30% на 70%\n
        HOTKEYS
        Рассчет Летнего пробега клавиша "Enter"
        Рассчет Зимнего пробега клавиша "Tab"
        """
    
        msgAbout = QMessageBox()
        msgAbout.setWindowTitle("Help")
#        msgAbout.setWindowIcon(QIcon('helpMenu.svg'))
# --------------------------------->  vvvvvv <------------------ установите свое         
        msgAbout.setWindowIcon(QIcon('im.svg'))
        
        msgAbout.setText(strAbout)
#        msgAbout.setIconPixmap(QPixmap("IconHelp.png"))
# --------------------------------->   vvvvvvvvvv <------------- установите свое 
        msgAbout.setIconPixmap(QPixmap("lena3.png"))
        
        msgAbout.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        msgAbout.exec()
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())




@VadimChekaev что не так?

да, то что нужно, спасибо!

@VadimChekaev пожалуйста
